# Swift - EventKit, unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple iOS application that deals with `EventKit` in order to allow the user to create their own calendar, events and alarms.

I am still in the beginning, I've added the `EventKit` framework and imported it in my class, but I always get an error when I want to declare this constant object:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
```

The error is: `Use of unresolved identifier 'EKEventStore'`

I tried importing `EventKitUI` and changed the deployment target (some of who faced this issue did that and the error disappeared) but the error is still popping-up.

Any ideas?

Comment: `import EventKit`. (no UI)

Comment: i did that already, @MatthiasBauch

Comment: Which delegate have you imported to your class? Does your class belong to a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Yes it belongs to UIViewController @CeceXX

Comment: Now another error appears with the import line, it says: [No such module 'EventKit']